# Asp.Net 5 Website Won't Load on IIS Express 10

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, asp.net5

I am trying to get my ASP.Net 5 MVC6 website to run on IIS Express 10 and it keeps giving me a an error which says:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

(Image Attached for full error)

I have successfully run the website from within Visual Studio 2015 Community but I want an 'Always on' solution so I don't have to keep starting and stopping the website from within VS.

I have the following in the IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config file:

```
<sites>
    <site name="Admin" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CMS\src\Admin\wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":12345:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

The URL I am using is: `http://localhost:12345/`

I have the following in my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
          <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

And my project.json file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Azure Web App. I managed to fix it by removing `startupTimeLimit` and `forwardWindowsAuthToken` properties from `web.config` `httpPlatform` tag. I found the solution by comparing my project to working one. Don't know if removal of properties have some side effects.

Comment: Seems to be enough if you remove the forwardWindowsAuthToken [see](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/10/28/resolve-an-asp-net-dnx-httpplatformhandler-cgi-application-exception-on-azure/)